# Indexing multidimensional numpy array inside numba's jitclass

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, indexing, jit, numba

I'm trying to insert a small multidimensional array into a larger one inside a numba jitclass. The small array is set specific positions of the larger array defined by an index list.

The following MWE shows the problem without numba - everything works as expected

```
import numpy as np

class NumbaClass(object):

    def __init__(self, n, m):
        self.A = np.zeros((n, m))

    # solution 1 using pure python
    def nonNumbaFunction1(self, idx, values):
        self.A[idx[:, None], idx] = values

    # solution 2 using pure python
    def nonNumbaFunction2(self, idx, values):
        self.A[np.ix_(idx, idx)] = values

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 6
    m = 8
    obj = NumbaClass(n, m)
    print(f'A =\n{obj.A}')

    idx = np.array([0, 2, 5])
    values = np.arange(len(idx)**2).reshape(len(idx), len(idx))
    print(f'values =\n{values}')

    obj.nonNumbaFunction1(idx, values)
    print(f'A =\n{obj.A}')

    obj.nonNumbaFunction2(idx, values)
    print(f'A =\n{obj.A}')
```

Both functions `nonNumbaFunction1` and `nonNumbaFunction2` do not work inside a numba class. So my current solution looks like this which is not really nice in my opinion

```
import numpy as np

from numba import jitclass      
from numba import int64, float64
from collections import OrderedDict

specs = OrderedDict()
specs['A'] = float64[:, :]

@jitclass(specs)
class NumbaClass(object):

    def __init__(self, n, m):
        self.A = np.zeros((n, m))

    # solution for numba jitclass
    def numbaFunction(self, idx, values):
        for i in range(len(values)):
            idxi = idx[i]
            for j in range(len(values)):
                idxj = idx[j]
                self.A[idxi, idxj] = values[i, j]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 6
    m = 8
    obj = NumbaClass(n, m)
    print(f'A =\n{obj.A}')

    idx = np.array([0, 2, 5])
    values = np.arange(len(idx)**2).reshape(len(idx), len(idx))
    print(f'values =\n{values}')

    obj.numbaFunction(idx, values)
    print(f'A =\n{obj.A}')
```

So my questions are:

- Does anyone know a solution to this indexing in numba or is there another vectorized solution?
- Is there a faster solution for `nonNumbaFunction1`?

It might be useful to know that inserted array is small (4x4 to 10x10), but this indexing appears in nested loops so it has to be quiet fast as well! Later I need a similar indexing for three dimensional objects too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of limitations on numba's indexing support, I don't think you can do any better than writing out the for loops yourself.  To make it generic across dimensions, you could use the [`generated_jit`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/generated-jit.html) decorator to specialize.  Something like this:

```
def set_2d(target, values, idx):
    for i in range(values.shape[0]):
        for j in range(values.shape[1]):
            target[idx[i], idx[j]] = values[i, j]

def set_3d(target, values, idx):
    for i in range(values.shape[0]):
        for j in range(values.shape[1]):
            for k in range(values.shape[2]):
                target[idx[i], idx[j], idx[k]] = values[i, j, l]

@numba.generated_jit
def set_nd(target, values, idx):
    if target.ndim == 2:
        return set_2d
    elif target.ndim == 3:
        return set_3d
```

Then, this could be used in your jitclass

```
specs = OrderedDict()
specs['A'] = float64[:, :]

@jitclass(specs)
class NumbaClass(object):
    def __init__(self, n, m):
        self.A = np.zeros((n, m))
    def numbaFunction(self, idx, values):
        set_nd(self.A, values, idx)
```

Comment: Thank you Form the nice answer. I did not know `generated_jit` yet. Looks promising to me. I will try it tomorrow!